# Why javascript is showing UNDEFINED?

Tags: javascript, html

I create some element inside HTML textarea using javascript. But javascript showing UNDEFINED.

What is the problem in my code?

```js
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = divs;
var divs = document.createElement("div");
var p = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("Text");
divs.appendChild(p);
p.appendChild(text);
```

```html
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

Comment: move the first line of your code to the bottom and use `... = divs.outerHTML` in this case

Comment: You use `divs` before defining it. Hence, `undefined`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are assigning the innerHTML to the variable divs before you create the variable.

Also, innerHTML should be used with a string. You are trying to assign an element.

Additionally, you cannot create elements within a textarea. You may want to use the contenteditable attribute on a div element instead.

Comment: I am trying to show HTML tags inside textarea. Is it possible?

Comment: @soheljaman if you want to show the HTML string inside of your textarea, use document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = divs.innerHTML; If you want to actually show HTML inside of a textarea, you need to use contenteditable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you need to reorder the lines like this :

In your code, the variable `divs` is not defined.

```js
var divs = document.createElement("div");
var p = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("Text");
p.appendChild(text);
divs.appendChild(p);
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = divs;
```

```html
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

Comment: Trying to assign divs to innerHTML might throw an error as well. innerHTML accepts html content as string. Also, cannot assign innerHTML to a textarea

Comment: @Everett Glovier   It will be returned as `[object HTMLDivElment]`. It will not show an error. But yes, you shouldn't use innerHTML on a textarea

Comment: But it is showing now [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: I am trying to show HTML tags inside textarea. Is it possible?

Comment: @soheljaman if you want to simply write those tags inside the textarea, you are looking for `.value`, not `.innerHTML`

Answer (score -1):

Because you are attaching them before you create the element.

That is not how hoisting works. You have to move the first line to the end.

Comment: I am trying to show HTML tags inside textarea. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

is's happen because this divs variable is in top and it's still undefined move the first line of your code to the bottom it will work ( i do not know why you are pushing html tag  into textarea make this textarea a div)

```js
var divs = document.createElement("div");
var p = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("Text");
divs.appendChild(p);
p.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = divs;
```

Comment: I am trying to show HTML tags inside textarea. Is it possible?

Comment: you can only push string into textarea like this document.getElementById("myText").innerText = "<div> hello world </div>";